# I can not extract data from a JSON type column in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I want to extract data from a json type column to insert them into a table in order to normalize a database.

The JSON type column is called "info" and an example of a record is the following:

```
[ { "major" : "International business", 
    "end" : "2007", 
    "name" : "Annamalai University",
    "degree" : "Master Degree", 
    "start" : "2005", "desc" : "" 
  }, 
  { "major" : "Mechanical Engineering", 
    "end" : "1990", 
    "name" : "Bharathidasan University", 
    "degree" : "Bachelor Degree", 
    "start" : "1990", "desc" : "" 
  }
]
```

This is my code:

```
SELECT id,
       (json_array_elements(info)->>'education')::json ->> 'key' AS key1 
FROM perfiles
WHERE id = 1252710;
```

This is the result I want to obtain:
[table result example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLxV6.jpg)

How should I do the query?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `json_to_recordset`

```
    SELECT  x.*
FROM pjson_table
   , json_to_recordset(myjson::json) x 
        (  major text
         , "end" text
         , name text
         , degree text
         , start text
         ,"desc" text
        )
```

[demo link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=8ae383bc88cefa2b5f81f94051aaee23)

```
 major                  end      name                   degree         start
International business  2007    Annamalai University    Master Degree   2005
Mechanical Engineering  1990    Bharathidasan University    Bachelor Degree 1990
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use  `cross join lateral` with `json_array_elements` and list the elements in the select

```
SELECT  p.id, 
           j->>'major'::text AS major, 
           (j->>'end')::int  AS "end", 
           j->>'name'        AS NAME, 
           j->>'degree'      AS degree, 
           j->>'start'       AS start, 
           j->>'desc'        AS "desc" 
FROM  perfiles p 
CROSS JOIN LATERAL json_array_elements(info) AS j
```

Or use `json_to_recordset` by specifying column list in the `FROM` clause

```
select p.id,
j.* FROM   perfiles p
  cross join lateral json_to_recordset(info) 
as j(major text, "end" int, name text, degree text, start int, "desc" text);
```

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=2033724854c9e2872c15c98d59cd8cc4)

Comment: Thanks the 3 answers were very Useful! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
select *
from (
  select
  json_to_recordset(info) as ed(major text, end int, name text, degree text, start int, desc text)
  from perfiles 
  where id = 1252710
)
```

Ref: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-json.html